# How websocket server keeps different clients info in an object?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, websocket

I'm trying to understand how websocket.js works by making a web chat application with registration form. I create a code block

```
var con = request.accept(null, req.origin);
var id = count++;
clients[id]=con;
```

and when I send a users text to server, server understands which user it is and sends reply to my front-end. I don't understand how it understands which message is written by which client.

If you can explain the workflow to me, I will appreciate it. Since I am a new learner, It is hard to make sense.

This is my full server code:

```js
var webSocketServer = require('websocket').server;
var http = require('http');
var count = 0;
var clients = {};
var users = [];


var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "127.0.0.1",
    user: "root",
    password: "123456",
    database: "web-chat"
});


var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {

    console.log((new Date())+' Received request for '+request.url);
    response.writeHead(404);
    response.end();

});

server.listen(1337, function () {
   console.log((new Date())+'Server listens on port 1337');
});

wsServer = new webSocketServer({
   httpServer: server
});


con.connect(function (err) {

    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("DB connected.");


    wsServer.on('request', function (request) {

        console.log((new Date())+'New connect request received'+request.remoteAddress);
        var connection = request.accept(null, request.origin);

        console.log((new Date()) + 'Connection accepted');

        var id = count++;
        clients[id] = connection;

        connection.on('message', function (message) {

            var parsedMsg = JSON.parse(message.utf8Data);
            var to = parsedMsg.to;


            if(to=='login') {

                var userid = parsedMsg.uid;
                var password = parsedMsg.pass;

                console.log(userid+ " " +password+ "to:"+to);

                con.query("SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE userid='" + userid + "' AND password='" + password + "'",
                    function (err, result, fields) {

                        if (err) throw err;

                        if (result == "") {
                            console.log("no such user");
                            var loginStatus = {'uid': userid, 'isMember': false};
                            clients[id].sendUTF(JSON.stringify(loginStatus));

                            return;
                        } else if (userid == result[0].userid) {
                            console.log("successfull login");

                            var loginStatus = {'uid': userid, 'isMember': true};

                            users[id]=userid;
                            console.log("Users ID: "+users[id]+" ID:"+id);

                            clients[id].sendUTF(JSON.stringify(loginStatus));

                            //UPDATE USER AS ONLINE IN DB
                            con.query("UPDATE user_table SET isonline ='1' WHERE userid='" + userid + "'", function (err, result) {
                                if (err) throw err;
                            });
                            //UPDATE USER AS ONLINE IN DB


                        }

                    });

            }else if(to=='chat'){

                var msg = parsedMsg.msg;

                for (var i in clients){


                    var chatLog = {'msg':msg,'user_id':users[id-1]};

                    clients[i].sendUTF(JSON.stringify(chatLog));
                }


            }else if(to=='register'){
                console.log("register page");
            }else if(to=='logout'){
                delete clients[id];
                console.log((new Date())+connection.remoteAddress+"is disconnected");
            }

        });
    });
});
```

This is index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <style>
        #frame-div{
            border: lightgray solid 1px;
            border-radius: 3px;
            width: 40%;
            margin: auto;
        }
        body{
            font-family: Calibri;
        }
        .label{
            display: table-cell;
            padding-top: 15px;
            padding-bottom: 5px;
        }
        .table{
            display: table;
        }
        .table-row{
            display: table-row;
        }
    </style>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

    var wsUri ="ws://127.0.0.1:1337";

    function init() {

        websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);

        websocket.onopen = function (event) {
            //
        };

        websocket.onmessage = function (event) {

            var content = document.getElementById("content");
            console.log("\n"+event.data);

            var parsedContent = JSON.parse(event.data);
            var uid = parsedContent.uid;
            var isMember = parsedContent.isMember;

            console.log(isMember);

            if (isMember){
                content.innerHTML="Welcome, "+uid+"<br>";
                window.location.href='chat.html';
            }
            else if(!isMember) {
                content.innerHTML+="Incorrect username / password!"+"<br>";
            }


        }

    }

    window.addEventListener("load",init,false);

    function Login() {
        var uid = document.getElementById("user-id").value;
        var pass = document.getElementById("password").value;

        websocket.send(JSON.stringify({'to':'login','uid':uid,'pass':pass}));

    }

</script>

<div id="frame-div" class="table">

    <div class="table-row">


        <div class="label">Kullanıcı Adı:</div>
        <div class="label"><input id="user-id" type="text"></div>

    </div>
    <div class="table-row">

        <div class="label">Parola:</div>
        <div class="label"><input id="password" type="password"></div>

    </div>
    <div class="table-row">

        <div class="label">
            <input type="button" value="Giriş Yap" onclick="Login()">
            <form action="registration.html" style="display: inline-block">
                <input type="submit" value="Üye Ol">
            </form></div>

    </div>

</div>

<p id="content"></p>


</body>
</html>
```

This is my chat.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <style>
        body{
            font-family: Calibri;
        }
        #main-frame{
            border: lightgray solid 0.5px;
            border-radius: 10px;
            background-color: burlywood;
            padding: 10px;
            width: 100%;

        }
        #left{
            border: lightgray solid 1px;
            border-radius: 10px;
            background-color: white;
            width: 80%;
            margin: auto;
            display: inline-block;
            height: 350px;


        }
        #right{
            border: lightgray solid 1px;
            border-radius: 10px;
            background-color: white;
            width: 15%;
            margin: auto;
            display: inline-block;
            height: 350px;

        }
        #bottom{
            padding-top: 20px;
        }

        #inp{
            width: 350px;
            height: 30px;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }
        #btn{
            width: 100px;
            height: 40px;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var wsUri = "ws://127.0.0.1:1337/";
    var output;

    function init() {
        output=document.getElementById("output");

        websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);

        websocket.onopen = function (evt) {
            output.innerHTML ="Connected";


        };

        websocket.onmessage = function (event) {

            var content = document.getElementById("chat-content");

            var parsedContent = JSON.parse(event.data);
            var user_id = parsedContent.user_id;
            var msg = parsedContent.msg;

            content.innerHTML+=user_id+" : "+msg+"<br/>";
        }
    }

    window.addEventListener("load",init,false);

    function sendMessage() {

        var textsend = document.getElementById("inp").value;

        websocket.send(JSON.stringify({'to':'chat','msg':textsend}));


    }
    
    function logout() {
        websocket.send(JSON.stringify({'to':'logout'}));
        window.location.href='index.html';
    }

</script>

<body>
    <div id="main-frame">
        <div id="left">
            Chat Main Screen:
            <p id="chat-content"></p>
        </div>
        <div id="right">
            Online Users:
        </div>

        <div id="bottom"><div><input type="text" id="inp"> <input type="button" value="Gönder" id="btn" onclick="sendMessage()"> <input
                type="button" value="Çıkış Yap" onclick="logout()" style="float: right; width: 90px; height: 40px;
                border-radius: 3px; margin-right: 30px"> </div></div>
    </div>

<div id="output"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When you say it knows which user sent it, how do you know if its the correct user? Are you going off of the ID, username? Also, which block of the code is returning the reply? Is it the first `else-if` block?

Comment: Hi, this code block returns response to chat.html:

`}else if(to=='chat'){

                var msg = parsedMsg.msg;

                for (var i in clients){


                    var chatLog = {'msg':msg,'user_id':users[id-1]};

                    clients[i].sendUTF(JSON.stringify(chatLog));
                }`